# Android LinearLayout programmatically one column left, one column float right

Tags: android, android-layout

My Android layout consists of 2 TextView inside a LinearLayout. However, I want the second text view to be align right.

Explanation:

[image]

```
// LinearLayout A
LinearLayout linearLayoutA = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayoutA.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearLayoutWorkoutPlansSessionsMain.addView(linearLayoutA);

// Title
TextView textViewExerciseTitle = new TextView(this);
textViewExerciseTitle.setText("Pull ups");
textViewExerciseTitle.setTextSize(16);
textViewExerciseTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
linearLayoutA.addView(textViewExerciseTitle);

// Reps & sets
TextView textViewSetsReps = new TextView(this);
textViewSetsReps.setText("8 x 4");
textViewSetsReps.setTextSize(16);
textViewSetsReps.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
textViewSetsReps.setPadding(20,0,0,0);
linearLayoutA.addView(textViewSetsReps);
```

Comment: why are you adding your layout on the run, why not create your layout(you can do it in fragment to avoid duplication)and give it values on runtime

Comment: Im doing it in a while loop because it is dynamic. The exercises depends on the users decicions.

Comment: another question -  this page needs to look like activity/fragment or dialog?

Comment: just make that view width match parent and gravity right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextView textViewSetsReps = new TextView(this);
    textViewSetsReps.setText("8 x 4");
    textViewSetsReps.setTextSize(16);
    textViewSetsReps.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textViewSetsReps.setPadding(20,0,0,0);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  1.0f);
    textViewSetsReps.setLayoutParams(params);
    textViewSetsReps.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    ll.addView(textViewSetsReps);
```

you could edit your sencond TextView like this !

Comment: "ll"  is your linearLayoutA